# How to convert rtp packet payload bytes H264/90000 to any video data?

Tags: java, udp, sip, h.264, rtp

[Studying the sip protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979598/how-to-convert-rtp-packet-payload-bytes-to-any-audio-data), I got to the topic of the H264 codec. I began to receive data in the form of rtp packets. I managed to successfully get the following data from the package: Payload type (in my case 97), Timestamp, Sequence number and payload data (byte array). Next, I want to draw images encoded in this data. On the android platform, I use the `android.media.MediaCodec` class. I follow examples like [MediaCodec failing on S7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839215/mediacodec-failing-on-s7).

I create an instance of `MediaCodec`. Configuring with `MediaFormat`. Then I transfer the received bytes to `inputBuffer` and wait for updates via `dequeueOutputBuffer`. In my case, the `dequeueOutputBuffer` method always returns `MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER`.

I was trying to process bytes before passing to `MediaCodec`. Defined `nal_unit_type`. I get 7, 8 and 28. I also defined `startBit` and `endBit` in the package. I tried to glue all packages starting with `startBit` and ending with `endBit` and transfer them to `MediaCodec` in a glued form. The result is the same - the `dequeueOutputBuffer` method always returns `MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER`

Tell me what I missed.

The server sends the following information about the video to the SDP:

```
m=video 23542 RTP/AVP 97
b=TIAS:4096000
a=content:main
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=428028; max-fs=8192; packetization-mode=0; max-br=4096; max-fps=3000
a=sendrecv
```

Edit #1

For example, first received packet payload (array of unsigned byte):

```
27 42 00 28 95 a0 1e 00 89 f9 70 11 00 00 03 00
42 00 28 95 a0 1e 00 89 f9 70 11 00 00 03 00 01
00 28 95 a0 1e 00 89 f9 70 11 00 00 03 00 01 00
```

I would venture to suggest that this is a [Single NAL Unit Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984#section-5.6). This packet has no padding.
By [rfc3984/1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984#section-1.3) i got in first byte:

```kotlin
//                                           0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
//                                          +-----+---------+
//                                                |   type  |
//                                          +-----+---------+
val nal_unit_type = payload[0].toInt() and 0b0_0_0_1_1_1_1_1
```

`nal_unit_type == 7` And I decided that this package contains `Sequence Parameter Set` data. Next, I want to get the decrypt SPS and get useful information from it (width and height, frame rate ...)

I got in second byte:

```kotlin
//                                       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
//                                      +-+-+-----------+
//                                      |s|e|
//                                      +-+-+-----------+
val start_bit = payload[1].toInt() and 0b1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 != 0
//                                      +-+-+-----------+
val end_bit = payload[1].toInt() and   0b0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0 != 0
```

`start_bit == false` and `end_bit == true`

Starting from the third byte (`payload[2]`), I parse the SPS.

Edit #2

I was wrong when I decided that the second byte for `nal_unit_type` 7 or 8 is the FU header (with `start` and `end` bits). The second byte of the payload is already the first byte of the SPS. Thus, I managed to successfully decrypt the SPS and, for example, find out that the image size 1920/1080 is encrypted there (as was expected). But this has not yet helped me in any way to draw the resulting video stream to the android surface view.

Comment: You need to strip off the RTP H264 headers before you pass the NALs to the decoder, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184.

Comment: Specify what kind of header you are talking about. I have already separated payload and RTP header(payload type, timestamp, sequence...) and I only work with payload. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184#section-5.1 ?

Comment: The "RTP H264 NAL" Header. It counts as part of the RTP payload and is described in the sections following 5.1. In case it's useful https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/9c76f2210491923915f8d88c50560d1846d67d3a/src/net/RTP/RTPSession.cs#L1618.

Comment: I added "Edit #1". @AaronClauson, tell me if I correctly identified my package as a Single NAL Unit Packet.

Comment: @AaronClauson, following rfc3984/5.1 what you are talking about is the header which I have already separated from the payload. How exactly I did this can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/kepocnhh/8a0ac516f9c727ea7f5f4a8c6f23fbfa (`ByteArray.toRtpPacket` method). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The edit in your question looks correct to me (packetization-mode=0 means Single NAL Unit mode). The other thing is that unlike audio some encoded video packets will typically be spread across multiple RTP packets (mainly the key frames which are the most critical).You need to use the RTP marker bit to re-construct the encoded video frames, https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/7d3b8086e5d01a04a1c21a2c05afe713f83266a9/src/net/RTP/RtpVideoFramer.cs#L44.

Comment: my android camera gives back decoded h264 units in the order by type 7, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, ...
@AaronClauson Is there a way to determine for which rtp packets you need to set a marker as 0 or as 1, and for which to increase the timestamp? (to send to the server)

Comment: It seems I made some mistakes in my RTP NAL sending logic including the use of timestamps. This may be of interest to you as well https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/issues/321.